# iPhone muliti laanguage support application

Tags: iphone, ios

I wanna create my iPhone app in three languages. English & Punjabi & Gujarai.

"Gujarati" & "Punjabi" is not available in locale list of languages. so i can't able to create values folder like values-fr(french) and value-rs(russia).. like dat.. How can i develop this app with "Punjabi" & "Gujarati"?

Comment: adding some language: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5774877/xcode-4-adding-localization

Comment: Refer this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/360751/can-i-embed-a-custom-font-in-an-iphone-application

Answer (score 0):

IOS 4.3 onwards these fonts are supported : http://iosfonts.com/

If don't find the fonts then you can use custom fonts. Steps listed below

Just follow these steps:

1.Add your custom font files into your project using XCode as a resource
2.Add a key to your info.plist file called UIAppFonts.
3.Make this key an array
4.For each font you have, enter the full name of your font file (including the extension) as items to the UIAppFonts array
5.Save info.plist
6.Now in your application you can simply call [UIFont fontWithName:@"CustomFontName" size:12] to get the custom font to use with your UILabels and UITextViews, etc…