# Localization - Add additional language to localizable.strings file

Tags: xcode, localization, xcode4.4

I have found  [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5349066/how-to-localize-my-app-with-xcode-4) about how to add localization to an app. The answer is very extensive and very helpful.

There is just one thing:

When selecting the 'Localizable.strings' file I open the File Inspector and I click on the button 'Make localized..' within the Localization pane. 
In the pop-up I can select a language but there is actually only one language to select form; English. There are no other options. But OK, having the option English selected I click on the button 'Localize'.

Now, in the file inspector, within the Localization pane I see the option English selected.

My problem: I **do not have** a '+' button to add an additional language.

Doe anybody know what is causing this? How can I add an additional language?
I am using Xcode 4.4.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

You have to add the localization first in the "Localization" section of the "Info" tab for the project. Once added to the project, the new localization is available for the strings file.

Comment: Thank you Martin! I had to make the file localized first. Then I did what you said and that was al!

Comment: it doesn't work for me. u need a string file to add localization in info tab but u need to specify info tab in order to add the strings file!!!

Comment: @OMGPOP: I am sorry, but I cannot reproduce your problem. When I create a new project then it already contains at least the "InfoPlist.strings" file. You should also be able to create a new strings file without having the localization first. - Please tell me if I can help further.

Comment: @Brabbeldas  May I get to know how to make the file localized first?I did as above but didn't work.

Comment: @OMGPOP I can't get what you say. Can you tell me in detail? You're Really appreciated.

Comment: @anna: If you select the file then there should be a "Make localized ..." button in the file inspector on the right side of the Xcode window.