# Localize Localizable.strings with Xcode 4.5

Tags: ios, xcode, ios6, xcode4.5, localizable.strings

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Localization - Add additional language to localizable.strings file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12069175/localization-add-additional-language-to-localizable-strings-file)

With Xcode 4.5 SDK iOS 6.0, I cannot add localization to Localizable.strings file.
In Xcode 4.4.1- under the list of all added languages was a "+" to add other languages. But in Xcode 4.5 I can't see it and I can't add any other languages apart the default English.

[image]

Someone has resolved this problem ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 22, accepted):

If you select your top level project file in the Project Navigator, and then in the area on the right select your project under "PROJECT" and more to the right click the "Info" pane, there is a part called "Localizations" where you can add new languages to your project. Once done, you can add these languages to any file you wish to localize.

This is for Xcode 4.4.1 but I am pretty sure 4.5 allows this as well.

Comment: How do you add a second localizable strings file in the case where you want a separate table?