# How to add language to a Localizable.strings in xcode 4.5.1?

Tags: xcode, xcode4.5

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Localization - Add additional language to localizable.strings file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12069175/localization-add-additional-language-to-localizable-strings-file)
>   [Localize Localizable.strings with Xcode 4.5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12546355/localize-localizable-strings-with-xcode-4-5)

It seems that the small "+" button has disappeared in 4.5.1 in the File Inspector tab

Edit: this is not a duplicate. I think it changed from Xcode 4.5 to 4.5.1 So please reopen.

Comment: I think it is the same in Xcode 4.5 and 4.5.1: You add the new localization first to the project. Then you can select the localizations for each resource in the file inspector tab of the resource, as described in the above duplicates. - If this does not work for you, please update your question with a description of the problem and I will try to help.