# How to add localization language to Xcode 4.4?

Tags: xcode, localization

In reference to this guide:
[How to localize my app with Xcode 4?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5349066/how-to-localize-my-app-with-xcode-4)

I noticed that under Localization, my Xcode 4.4 shows no [+] button:

[image]

**How can I add languages to the Localization list?**

**Note:** I'm not using IB. I purely need a localized strings file with translated strings for a game.

My workaround so far: I created the de.lproj folders manually, copied the strings file into de.lproj, added it to Xcode and Xcode did recognize the file as german. Xcode also added German to the Localization list. I'm wondering if there is an easier way to do this (from within Xcode) instead of copying & adding the files manually?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Select your project from the project navigator to open the project editor. Select your project from the left side of the project editor. Click the Info button at the top of the editor. You should see a list of localizations along with a button to add a localization. Click the Add button and choose a language. A sheet will open that lets you choose what files to localize.

Comment: The sheet that lets me choose what files to localize contains every resource (i.e., every image, xib and storyboard file) in the project. All of them are preselected. If the project contains a few hundred files, how can I exclude all hundreds of files except for the single file I want to actually localize?

Comment: @user8472, I don't know of an easy way to exclude the resource files from the sheet that you don't want to localize. Either deselect the checkboxes manually or temporarily remove the resource files from the project, create the localization, and add the resource files back to the project.