# Xcode 8 how to add a language?

Tags: ios, xcode, localization, xcode8, localizable.strings

I want to translate my app in German and Japanese. I have read tutorials to make it but I cannot find the Base Internationalization box that I am supposed to check in the info tab of my app. Main parts in my info tab are "custom IOS target properties", "document types", "exported UTIs"... There is nothing about Localization.

I guess I have to manage it in the "custom IOS target properties" but I don't know how. There I have added the key "Localizations" with "English", "German" and "Japanese" values, and I also have a key "Localization native development region" with value "en".

Then I have added my Localizable.strings file in Base.lproj but in the File Inspector I can only see "Base" and "English" as Localization, there is nothing about German and Japanese.

I have also noticed that when I go to Editor > Add Localization, I cannot select any language.

Do you see what's wrong?

Thank you,

Alex

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to add localization language to Xcode 4.4?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12094860/how-to-add-localization-language-to-xcode-4-4)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Click on the project and add Localization languages
[image]

And then select your storyboard -> File inspector

[image]

Comment: I have just seen that my panel with "project" and "targets" was hidden, and targets was pre-selected :D It works now thank you!