# Localization and CocoaPods

Tags: ios, localization, cocoapods

I have a project that uses CocoaPods. As a result, I have a workspace which contains two projects: mine and Pods.

Pods contains code which I'd like to localize, and I've created `.strings` files in Pod. However, `NSLocalizedString` fails to load these strings. I suspect this happens because the `.strings` file is not in the main bundle, but there's no Pod bundle, because it is compiled into a static library.

Is there a better way to localize code in a CocoaPods project than in my main project?

Comment: Nope; I just put the localized strings in the main project in a separate group/directory.

Comment: Localization is changed in newles Xcode.
[look there][1]
I think, mb it's solved your issue.. :-/

  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5349066/how-to-localize-my-app-with-xcode-4

Comment: Not sure how that helps; my question was posted when Xcode was around 4.5. Can you point to something specific?

Comment: If you specify what your resources are in your Podfile, then they get copied to your App Bundle.  That said, Localization STILL isn't working...

Answer (score 12):

`NSLocalizedString` just invokes NSBundle's `localizedStringForKey:value:table:` so I wrote a NSBundle category to enable looking into several bundles (which in iOS are just folders):

```
NSString * const kLocalizedStringNotFound = @"kLocalizedStringNotFound";

+ (NSString *)localizedStringForKey:(NSString *)key
                              value:(NSString *)value
                              table:(NSString *)tableName
                       backupBundle:(NSBundle *)bundle
{
    // First try main bundle
    NSString * string = [[NSBundle mainBundle] localizedStringForKey:key
                                                               value:kLocalizedStringNotFound
                                                               table:tableName];

    // Then try the backup bundle
    if ([string isEqualToString:kLocalizedStringNotFound])
    {
        string = [bundle localizedStringForKey:key
                                         value:kLocalizedStringNotFound
                                         table:tableName];
    }

    // Still not found?
    if ([string isEqualToString:kLocalizedStringNotFound])
    {
        NSLog(@"No localized string for '%@' in '%@'", key, tableName);
        string = value.length > 0 ? value : key;
    }

    return string;
}
```

Then redefined `NSLocalizedString` macro in my prefix file:

```
#undef  NSLocalizedString
#define NSLocalizedString(key, comment) \
[NSBundle localizedStringForKey:key value:nil table:@"MyStringsFile" backupBundle:AlternativeBundleInsideMain]
```

The same for other macros if needed (i.e. `NSLocalizedStringWithDefaultValue`)

Answer (score 5):

[@Rivera](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1049134/rivera) **Swift 2.0** version:

```swift
static let kLocalizedStringNotFound = "kLocalizedStringNotFound"

static func localizedStringForKey(key:String,
                                  value:String?,
                                  table:String?,
                                  bundle:NSBundle?) -> String {
    // First try main bundle
    var string:String = NSBundle.mainBundle().localizedStringForKey(key, value: kLocalizedStringNotFound, table: table)

    // Then try the backup bundle
    if string == kLocalizedStringNotFound {
        string = bundle!.localizedStringForKey(key, value: kLocalizedStringNotFound, table: table)
    }

    // Still not found?
    if string == kLocalizedStringNotFound {
        print("No localized string for '\(key)' in '\(table)'")
        if let value = value {
            string = value.characters.count > 0 ? value : key
        } else {
            string = key
        }
    }

    return string;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

1. You should not put any file in the Pods project, because the `pod` command will recreate the project again and again.

   So put the string files in your own project.
2. If you want to ship localized string files in your *own Pod*, you should include it in a bundle and make sure, the bundle will be installed in your Podspec file.

For example:

```
def s.post_install(target)
    puts "\nGenerating YOURPOD resources bundle\n".yellow if config.verbose?
    Dir.chdir File.join(config.project_pods_root, 'YOURPOD') do
        command = "xcodebuild -project YOURPOD.xcodeproj -target YOURPODResources CONFIGURATION_BUILD_DIR=../Resources"
        command << " 2>&1 > /dev/null" unless config.verbose?
        unless system(command)
            raise ::Pod::Informative, "Failed to generate YOURPOD resources bundle"
        end

        File.open(File.join(config.project_pods_root, target.target_definition.copy_resources_script_name), 'a') do |file|
            file.puts "install_resource 'Resources/YOURPODResources.bundle'"
        end
    end
end
```

Comment: So, the problem is that strings that are in the Pods project are not being loaded using NSLocalizedString. Even if a Pod ships with localization files, I can't use them without copying there into my project.

Comment: Actually, I read your response too fast - you might be on the right track. I can't verify the answer at the moment, so I'll rely on upvotes instead.

Comment: Any success on above issue? I need to add new language support in existing sdk

Answer (score 3):

The best approach for localizing resources in a pod (public or private is indifferent) is to add the `.strings` localization files to the pod bundle.

The main app is very picky when comes to pick up the localization files from the pod frameworks, here the steps you must follow:

**1** - Create the Localizable.strings and all the other `*.strings` files you need for your localization and put them in a folder, something like this:

[image: strings folder structure]

Some constraints to respect:

- The folders name must be `XX.lproj`, where XX is your **EXACT** language name, note: `en` != `en-GB` != `en-US`
- All the `lproj` folder need to be at the same level
- Every `lproj` folder need to have the same number of `.strings` files and with the same names

**2** - Configure your `.podspec` file so the pod can pick up the localization correctly and copy them in the `.framework`.

Example:

```
  s.resource = 'your_path/Localizations/**/*', '... possibly other resources'
```

after doing `pod install` the result in your Development Pods folder should be something like this:

[image]

One important thing to check is that created framework is that all the `.lproj` folder need to be on the **root folder**, otherwise are not picked up correctly by the main app.

**3** - In your pod's code instead than the usual `NSLocalizedString` you must use `NSLocalizedStringFromTableInBundle`:

```
NSLocalizedStringFromTableInBundle(@"My string", nil, [NSBundle bundleForClass:[MCLoginContext class]], @"String context")
```

The entire process is very delicate and annoying, but that's should be all.

Answer (score -2):

for swift you could use a Loc enum:

```
enum Loc : String{
case ok = "OK"
case cancel = "Cancel"

var localized: String {
    let s = self.rawValue
    let bundle = Bundle(for: <classname inside the bundle>.self)
    let result = NSLocalizedString(s, tableName: nil, bundle: bundle, value: "", comment: "")
    return result;
}
```

}

And use it so:

```
let s = Loc.ok.localized
print(s)
```