# NSLocalizedString for Cocoapods

Tags: xcode, cocoapods, nslocalizedstring

I have a project in Swift and it uses a few languages (3 at the moment). I added them using "Localizations" tab in Project tab. Then I'd use Editor -> Export for Localization.. to generate an `Xliff` file which would contain all the `NSLocalized` strings and translated storyboards in my project. After translating, I'd import `Xliff` back and it's all done. Very convenient.

I'm also using a few `Cocoapods` which already have `NSLocalizedString`'s inside, just sitting for me to translate them. The problem is, when exporting my `Xliff`, it wouldn't pick up any other untranslated strings within my workspace, just within the project.

How would I go about translating those strings and also making sure that they stay there when I `pod update` next time?

Comment: How did you eventually solve your issue?

Comment: Unfortunately, the best way is to provide the pod translation as part of the pod's resources, have a look: https://stackoverflow.com/a/63074608/465916

Answer (score 1):

> How would I go about translating those strings...

see [Localization and CocoaPods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12874678/localization-and-cocoapods).

> ...making sure that they stay there when I pod update next time?

If you are using public CocoaPods (i.e. from GitHub), it is of good etiquette (*if not your duty*) to collaborate and `clone`, localize, then `git push` back to community. This will ensure that you `pod install`, as well as everyone else's `pod install` will contain localized data.

---

It is a bit of a tedious process, but one adopted by countless Pod projects, including, but not limited to [Appirater](https://github.com/arashpayan/appirater).

Comment: I barely understand how ``NSLocalizedString``'s work and you're talking etiquette or duty? That's why I asked this question in the first place using ``Swift``. Btw thanks for editing it out and pointing to and ``obj-c`` answer, which I had already seen before anyway.

Comment: The **Swift** version of the **Obj-C** response is now posted on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12874678/localization-and-cocoapods/31695008#31695008. I understand your frustration on `CocoaPods` ethics, and recommend you explore sharing your hard work.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the Swift version. So where do I put my translations? As they are now - in Localizable.string files? and how do I use this swift method? The original author talks about macros, but I'm not sure what those are in Swift.