# Add localization to pod by adding strings file

Tags: ios, swift, localization, cocoapods

I have local pod added to app like this.

```
 pod 'WifiModule', :path => '../WifiModule'
```

Now I need to localize the string inside the module. Which is my local pod in app.
How can I do it ? When I try to add localization, it shows no file in the list.

I don't have a main storyboard in my pod. I don't want to localize with coding inside my class but by adding localizae string.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Localization and CocoaPods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12874678/localization-and-cocoapods)

Comment: No, Its not same. As I have a local pod file. 
Moreover, it should stay with my project even i do pod install or update.

Comment: Also I don't want to localize them with my code but add strings to my pod file to get them localize