# How can I get EventKitUI to use the device language?

Tags: ios, ios5, eventkit, ekevent

I'm using an `EKEventEditViewController` to create, edit and delete events from the event store, but it always displays in **English**. Is there a way to localize it, so it will use the default language of the device?

Comment: Is your device default language English?

Comment: No, I tested it in spanish and english devices.

Comment: What is the "**Localization native development region**" set to in your **info.plist**? See this example: http://snapplr.com/r7rs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set the **Localization native development region** in your **info.plist** to the desired language you want in this view controller.

Also see [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5349066/how-to-localize-my-app-with-xcode-4).

Comment: **Localization native development region** is **en**, I changed to **es** but still displaying in English, the problem with String file, is that I haven't found how change the components in the EKEventEditController.