# Apple appstore and countries

Tags: ios, localization, app-store

I'm researching the following questions and not much has been able to get so far. Hopefully you could help me to understand.

1. Assuming an app is published to the US app store; will a user with russian app store setting be able to download it?
2. Assuming an app is published to the Russian appstore;  will a user with US app store setting be able to download it?
3. Is there such a thing as global availability, or should an app be submitted into an every store it is supposed to be available at?
4. How is Russian localization different from submitting an app version to Russian app store?
5. What are the best practices for submitting an app designed for non-English speaking audience (Russian in my case) ?

I'd willingly read a relevant manual on that, please point me if you know one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Question 1, 2 and 3 are the same;-) When you submit the app you can choose in which store it comes up in. You will only need to submit it once.

Russian Localization is things like specific languages that will come up if you download it in Russia with Russian settings. if your app does not accomodate that, then it will just be in english or whatever language you have for your app by default.

Answer (score 7):

**Warning: This Answer is BIG**

Well by default your application goes to all countries (read later in the post and I will post all the countries names). Buy if you don't localized your application (like in Russia they speak Russian, and if your application is only in English the app is useless for only Russian speaking users).

But what if I want my Application only running in America or etc:

- Log into iTunesConnect and click "Manage Your Apps."
- Select your app and click the "Rights and Pricing" button.
- You can select the stores you want from this page.
- (If you see a line at the bottom that says "Unless you select specific stores...", your app is already for sale in all stores.)

Q: How to localize my app with Xcode 4?

A: Check out this links: [How to localize my app with Xcode 4?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5349066/how-to-localize-my-app-with-xcode-4), http://www.raywenderlich.com/2876/how-to-localize-an-iphone-app-tutorial, and http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oMHRYDEbgpg :)

The Official list of Countries as of May 18, 2012: Link to official list: http://support.apple.com/kb/TS3599 (scroll down to view more countries :)

```
 Algeria 
Angola 
Anguilla 
Antigua & Barbuda 
Argentina 
Armenia 
Australia 
Austria 
Azerbaijan 
Bahamas 
Bahrain 
Barbados 
Belarus 
Belgium 
Belize 
Bermuda 
Bolivia 
Botswana 
Brazil 
British Virgin Islands 
Brunei 
Bulgaria 
Canada 
Cayman Islands 
Chile 
China 
Colombia 
Costa Rica 
Croatia 
Cyprus 
Czech Republic 
Denmark 
Dominica 
Dominican Republic 
Ecuador 
Egypt 
El Salvador 
Estonia 
Finland 
France 
Germany 
Ghana 
Greece 
Grenada 
Guatemala 
Guyana 
Honduras 
Hong Kong 
Hungary 
Iceland 
India 
Indonesia 
Ireland 
Israel 
Italy 
Jamaica 
Japan 
Jordan 
Kazakhstan 
Kenya 
Kuwait 
Latvia 
Lebanon 
Lithuania 
Luxembourg 
Macau 
Macedonia 
Madagascar 
Malaysia 
Mali 
Republic of Malta 
Mauritius 
Mexico 
Montserrat 
Moldova 
Netherlands 
New Zealand 
Nicaragua 
Niger 
Nigeria 
Norway 
Oman 
Pakistan 
Panama 
Paraguay 
Peru 
Philippines 
Poland 
Portugal 
Qatar 
Romania 
Russia 
St. Kitts & Nevis 
St. Lucia 
St. Vincent & The Grenadines 
Saudi Arabia 
Senegal 
Singapore 
Slovakia 
Slovenia 
South Africa 
South Korea 
Spain 
Sri Lanka 
Suriname 
Sweden 
Switzerland 
Taiwan 
Tanzania 
Thailand 
Trinidad & Tobago 
Tunisia 
Turkey 
Turks & Caicos 
Uganda 
United Arab Emirates 
United Kingdom 
United States 
Uruguay 
Uzbekistan 
Venezuela 
Vietnam 
Yemen
```