# 3rd Party Language support (Xcode + iOS)

Tags: ios, internationalization

I want to write my iOS app for serbian. I load a plist file with all the strings in, and then I NSLog it just to be sure. I also use special characters, like

```
š
```

but in the log it prints the letter as

```
\U0161
```

is this supposed to happen? I haven't tried using it on a UILabel yet, but do I need to use some sort of special font or something?

Comment: Checkout this complete answer. It worth to go over it. Maybe you missed something? I just did this for app of mine for non-english language a few weeks back and it worked just fine http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5349066/how-to-localize-my-app-with-xcode-4

Comment: @Sam Budda thanks for your answer, I would do it like that, but I'm not using storyboards or xibs, and as far as I know, you can't localize implementation files

Comment: @Till thanks, that was the answer, I'm sorry for not going through SO so well, but thanks for pointing that out, btw, it DID display correct in a UILabel without encoding