# How to translate my iOS App

Tags: ios, translate

this is a very basic question. Too basic so I can't find a simple answer.

I have my 'iOS' app in French. I want to translate it in English.

How can I do that ? (I speak English but I don't know what is the protocol in Xcode to create "a dictionnary of the strings" in French/English in my app)

Thanks

Comment: localization is documented in the iOS info --- not sure where tho.

Comment: See the iOS docs: [Internationalization Programming Topics](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPInternational/BPInternational.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000171-SW1)

Answer (score 1):

You have to use Localization... The tutorial I used and recommend is here: http://www.raywenderlich.com/2876/how-to-localize-an-iphone-app-tutorial
If you are still having trouble check out this answer in stack overflow: [How to localize my app with Xcode 4?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5349066/how-to-localize-my-app-with-xcode-4)

Comment: @GoldXApp If this answer helped be sure to give it a check