# How to localize my app with Xcode 5?

Tags: ios, xcode, localization, internationalization, xcode5

This is a follow up question (and answer) on the [How to localize my app with Xcode 4?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5349066/how-to-localize-my-app-with-xcode-4/11282424#11282424) question.

How do I localize my app with Xcode 5.x?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

It's quite simple once you understand it.

The first thing you want to do is add a localization file to your project.
 To do so, simply select your project's main group

[image: main group],

then, from the toolbar, select `File → New → File...` (or just hold down `⌘N`)
[image: New File].

Under the `Resource` category, select `Strings File` [image: Select "Strings File"],
 and name it `Localizable.strings` (note that it is case sensitive) [image: localizable.strings Name].

Now that we have our localizable file, we can click on the `Localize...` button, in the `File Inspector`

[image: File Inspector].

Xcode is going to ask you if you want to localize the file, just click on `Localize` with `Base` selected
[image: Localize?].

Now this next part is a bit tricky. We need to enter our project's `Info` section, to do so, click on the project file in Xcode's `Navigator`, then to your right you'll see a category named `PROJECT`, click on your project file under this category

[image: Project File].

Now we can add our desired language under the `Localizations` category. I'll add `Norwegian`

[image: Languages].

It's `important` that we only leave our `Localizable.strings` file checked in the menu that appears
[image: Localizable.strings file checked].

Now we can expand our `Localizable.strings` file in the `Navigator` to see our localizable files
[image: Strings file expanded].

We now how our `Base` file (within our `Localizable.strings` file), which will be our app's "main language", and our previously selected language.

It's important to know that the structure of these files needs to be identical. You'll see what I mean in just a sec.

In our `Base`, I'll add a string named `it_worked`, and add it's localization

[image: it_workedEN].

And in our previously selected language (In my case `Norwegian`), i'll add the same string `it_worked` (to keep the structure), but with a different localization

[image: it_workedNO].

Now that we have our localized file, we can make our app read it when needed.

I added a `UILabel` to my app, so that we can make our app display the localized text.

```
[myLabel setText:NSLocalizedString(@"it_worked", nil)];
```

Now if I launch my app, we'll see our base language

[image: Base Language (EN)],

and if I change the language of the simulator to Norwegian, we'll see our other language

[image: Other Language (NO)].

Answer (score 3):

You don't need to add the uilabel and change the text on code.

You can take advanced of the User Defined Runtime Attributes:

http://cupobjc.blogspot.com.es/2014/04/interfaz-builder-localization.html

First define a new category for UILabel:

```
#import "UILabel+Localized.h"

@implementation UILabel (Localized)
-(void) setTextLocalized:(NSString *)aText{
     [self setText:NSLocalizedString(aText, nil)];
}
@end
```

Then in the interface builder, User Defined Runtime Attributes :

textLocalized   String     your string to localized

[image]