# How to add localisation in Main.strings?

Tags: ios

I have an existing localised application with several Main.strings files.

Now, I add several objects like UILabel for example.

How can I add these strings in the existing Main.strings files?

-Edit*

I currently do that manually by opening each Main.strings file and copying an existing translation:

```
/* Class = "IBUILabel"; text = "Developped by"; ObjectID = "SKE-KN-dba"; */
"SKE-KN-dba.text" = "Developped by";


/* Class = "IBUILabel"; text = "I change this text"; ObjectID = "Object ID"; */
"Object ID.text" = "I change this text";
```

Where I take the "Object ID" value from the Objet's identity inspector.

Don't know if it exists a better way.

Comment: Try this way :: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5349066/how-to-localize-my-app-with-xcode-4

Comment: @Praphin, it seems this is to a language. It's not what I want. I just want to add strings to existing translation. So, I currently do that manually as explained in my edit.