# iOS How to localize for both Spain and international?

Tags: ios, xcode, localization, internationalization

I want to have a specific version of Localizable.strings file to serve for people in Spain. However, in the case of general Spanish, i want to serve a different file.

Where is the documentation on how this is done?

or is it just that i need two Localizable.strings files in both `es.lproj` and `es-ES.lproj` ?

Also, is it as easy as just creating the folder `es.lproj` with `Localizable.strings` file, and then in xCode do "Add files to project" ?

Answer (score 2):

1. What you should do is to localize your xcode project. The document for xcode project localization is here(https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPInternational/LocalizingYourApp/LocalizingYourApp.html)
2. There are different Spanish language, such as Spanish-Mexico(es-mx) and Spanish-Peru(ex-pe). Please refer to here for more details(http://www.science.co.il/Language/Locale-codes.asp).
   And if you just need to support Spanish - Spain (Traditional) language, either es or es-ES is Okay.
3. Creating the folder es.lproj with Localizable.strings file is not work for localization. You should localize the project. Please refer to 1 or here([How to localize my app with Xcode 4?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5349066/how-to-localize-my-app-with-xcode-4)) for project localization.