# Change Language of Text displayed in default UIAlertView in iOS

Tags: ios, localization

I wanna change language of default UIAlerts

For example:Alert of Push Notifications Permission when first time an app launches from app manually....

Please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**This is not possible**. That message is coming from iOS. So it will show the text based on user language selection in his Settings. However, you can set a custom language for your app and then show a relevant message to your user.

If your app is in multiple language you can localize it. [How to localize my app with Xcode 4?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5349066/how-to-localize-my-app-with-xcode-4)

Comment: Can we change language in settings from app in background

Comment: Nope, we can't. But you can always ask user to do that. But I suggest, this is not a good behavior.

Comment: Thanks for your Suggestions